# Preventing Chrome from applying media queries to the print version of pages

Tags: google-chrome, printing, media-queries

I'm looking to create a print version of pages for a site I'm building and all seemed to be going  well until I tested in Chrome. I'm experiencing a maddening issue whereby Chrome is defaulting to certain responsive specific media queries (responsive.css) while ignoring any dimensions set via @media print (print.css). I can't for the life of me figure out a solution to this.

I *think* this is perhaps related to the Chromium / Bootstrap bug described as [Incorrect viewport size used for media queries when printing.](http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/). But I've been trying to fix this for so long that I'm now incapable of analyzing it any longer.

A link to the site can be [found here](http://www.hia.lmcgurdy.dara.link/ci/app_dev.php/comparison/step3?plan_ids=299%7C380%7C402&initial_plans=402%7C299%7C380%7C103%7C338%7C403%7C296%7C381%7C285%7C246%7C271%7C484%7C43%7C480%7C339%7C87%7C382%7C96%7C297%7C65%7C113%7C66%7C22%7C220%7C18%7C55%7C115%7C119%7C75%7C79%7C243%7C1%7C2%7C329%7C244%7C76%7C153%7C44%7C80%7C20%7C98%7C117%7C121%7C164%7C168%7C162%7C163%7C165%7C306&accommodation_level=1&source=step2&&restore=true). So any suggestions on why this is happening and how to prevent it? A similar issue was [reported on SO in July '14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650543/print-media-queries-being-ignored-in-chrome) but I've not had any success with the solutions (though I have yet to try the js option and I'm reluctant to do so) and I'm hopin that some fix has arisen since.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late response, but I just ran into this problem and solved it using the method [described here](https://blog.donnierayjones.com/2014/10/fix-bootstrap3-printing/). It overrides the grid in a print media query using the `make-grid` mixin.