# BOOTSTRAP - How to remove table border while printing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing, border

I can remove while browsing, but when I put the code under the @media print section, nothing happens (I have code inside this block, works perfectly).
Seems like a Chrome default behaviour. Any solutions?

Comment: Maybe this is the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24656057/3585500

Comment: Not really, i already have a css block for media print, and it works, just this border rule that i can't override so far.